# MapBox GL and styling for data driven labels

Tags: style, mapbox-gl

I can use the data driven feature to color points, works great

```javascript
MAP.addLayer({
"id": "schools",
"type": "circle",
"source": "markers",
"layout": { },
"paint": {
    "circle-radius": 8
    'circle-color': {               // for data driven colors need v0.18.0
        'property': 'type',
        'type': 'categorical',
        'stops': [
            ['ELEMENTARY', '#009900'], 
            ['MIDDLE', '#cc00ff'], 
            ['HIGH', '#1666ff'] 
   }
}   
});
```

I also want the label to be the same color as the point. All my text labels default to the first stop color. Can I use the data driven feature for text labels, and if so what am I doing wrong?

```javascript
MAP.addLayer({
"id": "school_label",
"type": "symbol",
"source": "markers",
"layout": {
    "text-font": ["Open Sans Regular"],
    "text-field": "{full_name}",
    "symbol-placement": "point",
    "text-size": 10
},
"paint": {
    //"text-color": "#ff0000",
    'text-color': {
        'property': 'type',
        'type': 'categorical',
        'stops': [
            ['ELEMENTARY', '#009900'], 
            ['MIDDLE', '#cc00ff'], 
            ['HIGH', '#1666ff'] 
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just read this in a mapbox blog, and to answer my own question I cannot do data driven labels.
"data driven styles have been one of the biggest tasks in Mapbox GL’s history, but they stand to change everything. Right now we just support data-driven styles for Mapbox GL JS, and only for circle-radius and circle-color."

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Answer (score 1):

Just tried with version 0.37 and it works now.